# Upside down - iOS Xcode not working while using autolayout

Tags: ios, autorotate, screen-rotation

using autolayout feature in xcode 6.3.2 , i am able to adjust my views, buttons and text fields for iPad and iPhone. but for upside down my view doesnt chagne, Any idea How do we support upside down mode using auto layout without adding any code to your view controllers. I have also checked the upside down mode in project settings in xcode.

sample code :- https://github.com/deepesh259nitk/OrientationSupport

screen shots below.

[image]

[image]

max.

Comment: Upside down is for iPads only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also need to override `-supportedInterfaceOrientations` inside each view controller you want to support upside down orientation, since by default that method returns `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown` on iPhone.

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```